# How to use Minio presigned URLs with Go

Tags: go, object-storage, minio

### Goal:

Implement reading Minio objects through signed URLs (using `github.com/minio/minio-go/v6`)

### Attempt:

I followed the example from github:
https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/master/examples/s3/presignedgetobject.go

and using `PresignedGetObject()`, I end up with a `net/url` struct. When I concatenate the `url.Host` and `url.Path` value the result is something like: `localhost:9000/inputs/2ea471a5521c.pdb`. Which simply links to the object in Minio UI.

I expected the client to generate a signed URL that enables downloading the object when queried with `curl` or else, something like this in Google Cloud Storage:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#example

Am I missing some additional logic or have I misinterpreted what minio pre-signed URLs are? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the presigned url as string you can simply call

```
presignedURL.String()
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.String

Comment: Ah, perfect, so my mistake was with Go syntax, not the minio client.
Thank you